# Install postfixadmin?

Tags: email, server

Is there any complete guid for install postfix admin rather than official install guid?

I tried to install postfix admin several times. But I couldn't. I tried with official installation text file and several online tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing PostfixAdmin is not very hard, in-fact it's very simple.
PostfixAdmin is basically just a Apache+PHP+MySQL setup.

The bigger problem I think users are experiencing is how to make Postfix actually use the database backend and to "understand" the data it gets from it - What they refer to as the integration part in their INSTALL.txt for PostfixAdmin.

Take a look at the Postfix integration documentation at their GitHub page.
https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin/blob/master/DOCUMENTS/POSTFIX_CONF.txt

There are no easy way to just copy-pasta aka spray-and-pray install a complete SMTP/Mail system. Also I would not recommend it as you would have a very hard time to debug problems in your setup later on - And trust me SMTP servers always have problems :)

But basically once you have installed PostfixAdmin and that part works (i.e you can log onto the page, navigate around postfixadmin and add domains and so on) then you move on to adding all the .cf files it needs in the postfix etc directory.

Again, use that file above as reference. Or even search for multiple guides on Google. You will see that more or less all of them are doing the same steps.

Once your postfix is setup to talk "mysql" you can start to debug the mail.log files for problems that will (again trust me they will) come up. That will typically be beginner mistakes like the .cf files are not looking up the right data in the tables or using wrong parameters for email vs domain or that postfix don't have mysql support enabled and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @davidbl, the error message which I am getting after installing postfixadmin is this. 403-Forbidden "You don't have permission to access /postfixadmin/setup.php on this server (in browser page, I tried to access postfixadmin using this url: "localhost/postfixadmin/setup.php")." Do you know the root cause of this error?

Comment: @AnushkaUdithaBandara it's hard to say right of the bat what could cause that. You say "localhost" so I assume you are sitting directly on the server where you installed postfixadmin ? Try using it's local/public IP address instead like "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/postfixadmin/setup.php" also check that the file permissions are set correctly for your /postfixadmin directory. Should be owned by the Apache user (www-data) in most cases and have read/write permissions.

Comment: Yes, I am on where I installed postfixadmin. I set ownership correctly to the  Apache user and still I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Thank you @davidbl for the help :)